In docusaurus: Insert block of the same html code into every page
So the question is in the title.
How could I add the same static block of HTML code into every page, generated by docusaurus?
Let the sample code be <p>Hello World<p>, that I would like to insert right after the existing <body> tag (inserting inside <head>...</head> s also OK - at the end I need to insert a custom analytics counting script together with some HTML tags)
I have found that injectHtmlTags does that, however I don't know how to use it.
They reference a non-existing docusaurus-plugin/src/index.js file. Even if I create the folders and the file with content
export default function (context, options) {
  return {
    name: 'docusaurus-plugin',
    loadContent: async () => {
      return {remoteHeadTags: await fetchHeadTagsFromAPI()};
    },
    injectHtmlTags({content}) {
      return {
        preBodyTags: [`<p> Hello world </p>`],
      };
    },
  };
}

nothing changes in final (built for production) web-pages.
Should I install some plugin and, if so, how should I do that?
Should I modify docusaurus.config.js configuration?

As I understand you want to include custom script to your app. I had similar issue but in your case you are saying custom script with some html tags. I can share solution with including only script if it is your case.
